# Россия заняла 56-ю позицию из (среди?)104 стран

Tags: предлоги

Россия заняла 56-ю позицию из 104 стран.

Может быть, вместо *из* надо писать *среди*?

Answer (score 1):

> Может быть, вместо *из* надо писать *среди*?

Конечно, СРЕДИ.